# Unsupported Media Type when deploying OTA Blackberry App

Tags: deployment, blackberry, jar, blackberry-jde, jad

I have a blackberry app that I am trying to deploy OTA (over the air).

I have set the MIME type on my server to be:

```
cod  application/vnd.rim.cod

jad     text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor

jar     application/java-archive
```

When I access the JAD file on my web-server through the BlackBerry Browser, I get the message

```
Unsupported Media Type
```

and then a prompt to download the JAD. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Those MIME types are correct.  You might want to double check that your webserver is sending back the correct Content-Type header using a command such as "curl -I"

Answer (score 1):

Double checked MIME type settings and there was a typo. They have to be EXACT or there will be problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod

AddType  text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor

AddType  application/java-archive
```

You need to add these to your .hataccess file of directory in which these files are if using apache server.

Comment: I am sure you might be messing them up. You need to use thoes in .htaccess Simply make a text file with this extension and add this content upload it to directory.